# Laravel getting data with inner relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this data base structure.

[image]

Here is my `Customer` Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';


    /**
     * Customer Address Relationship 
     * 
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function address()
    {
        return  $this->hasOne(Address::class, 'address_id', 'address_id');
    }
}
```

`Address` model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'address_id';


    /**
     * An Address have one city
     * 
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function city()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(City::class, 'city_id', 'city_id');
    }
}
```

I am calling

```
return Customer::with(['address'])->get();
```

I am getting `"city_id"` in the response but i want `city` in the response instead of "city_id". How can i get `city`?

```
{
        "customer_id": 1,
        "store_id": 1,
        "first_name": "MARY",
        "last_name": "SMITH",
        "email": "MARY.SMITH@sakilacustomer.org",
        "address_id": 5,
        "active": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-06T12:44:34.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-06T12:44:34.000000Z",
        "address": {
            "address_id": 5,
            "address": "1913 Hanoi Way",
            "address2": "",
            "district": "Nagasaki",
            "city_id": 463,
            "postal_code": "35200",
            "phone": "28303384290",
            "location": null,
            "created_at": "2023-02-06T12:44:26.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-06T12:44:26.000000Z"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship but also specify additional query conditions for the eager loading query. You can accomplish this by passing an array of relationships to the with method where the array key is a relationship name and the array value is a closure that adds additional constraints to the eager loading query

```
return Customer::with(['address' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('address_id', 'address', 'address2', 'city')
    ->leftJoin('cities', 'addresses.city_id', '=', 'cities.city_id');
}])
->get();
```

> note: select statement must include primary key else select won't working and null value will be returned. Without the relation primary key the other table won't be able to map the relation.